# Pandas Series: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to develop a conditional statement that returns a boolean based on a asset pricing dataset (pandas Series).

```
percent_change = calculate_percent_change(series)
highest_close = calculate_max(series)
lowest_close = calculate_max(series)

buy = percent_change>=2 and series==highest_close
sell = series == lowest_close
return (1*buy - 1*sell)
```

This code is meant to return a 1, 0 or -1 based on the results of the conditions above

I'm receiving this error due to the 'AND' in the buy conditional statement. If I remove the AND, the code runs fine, see below:

```
percent_change = calculate_percent_change(series)
highest_close = calculate_max(series)
lowest_close = calculate_max(series)

buy = percent_change>=2
sell = series == lowest_close'
```

Structuring an if-statement doesn't work either.

How can I add multiple conditions to the 'buy' boolean?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare a Pandas `series` to a single `int` or `float`

Try to print `series == lowest_close`

You'll get something like

```
False
True
False
dtype: bool
```

Which is a series of booleans, the `and` and `or` keywords require your inputs to be a single boolean and not a series. The same thing would've happened if you would've tried.

```
if series == lowest_close
```

As the error says, the truth value of the series is ambiguous. Do you want it to be true if any of the value in the series is true? or if all of them are true or one in particular?

To fix this you need to more specifically think when you want sell to be `True` or `False`.

Comment: Yes, the answer returns a series of booleans, that's actually exactly what I want. The issue is I cant seem to add TWO CONDITIONS to return a boolean for that line of the series. thats where the error comes from. everything in my above statement works flawlessly until I add AND into the buy condition.

Comment: You cannot compare a series of booleans and a single boolean with the `and` keyword. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: Edited my above comment.